# Error with placing widgets

Tags: python, tkinter

This function is part of a class. so before this function is called there is another function that places in some buttons. but once this function is called the impression of previous buttons is left over:

[image: (this is what it looks like(the middle section))].

Please suggest a correction or a better way to do this.

```
def Add(self):

        for widget in Frame.winfo_children(self):
              widget.destroy()
        self.pack(expand=1)
        e1, e2 = StringVar(), StringVar()
        self.L = {}
        Label1 = Label(text="Enter your code:")
        E1 = Entry(textvariable=e1)
        def  F1():
              self.L["Code"] = e1.get()
              return
        B1 = Button(text="Ok", command=F1)
        Label2 = Label(text="Enter name:")
        E2 = Entry(textvariable=e2)
        def  F2():
              self.L["Name"] = e2.get()
              return
        B2 = Button(text="Ok", command=F)

        Label1.place(x=0, y=0)
        E1.place(x=167, y=0)
        B1.place(x=472, y=0)
        Label2.place(x=0, y=44)
        E2.place(x=167, y=44)
        B2.place(x=472, y=44)
```

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I don't understand your exact problem.   (See Bryan's comment also.)  I suggest using grid methods, as they are much more beginner-proof and easier even for experienced users, like myself.